# Switching Column Fields in Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a very large dataset with a wide range of variables for which I am making an in-Excel dashboard.

I want to swap Column fields one at a time (for example in the image below, change the Q1 value with Q2) without changing the rest of the dashboard.

This will be going to folks unfamiliar with pivot tables which is why I am looking for a macro solution rather than flipping the value in the pivot fields manually.

I have a 200 question Likert-scale survey and with the various fields to display, have the columns represent each question. I want to click a button to switch which question is displayed.

I found code online, but it breaks on the `pf.Orientation = xlHidden` line with

> Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the Orientation property of the PivotField class.

```vb
Sub Add_Column_Field()
'Remove all Column fields and add the Column field to the pivot table.
'The field is determined by the button text that calls the macro.

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim sField As String

'Set variables
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
sField = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame.Characters.Text
  
'Remove existing fields
For Each pf In pt.ColumnFields
    pf.Orientation = xlHidden
Next pf
  
'Add field that button was clicked for
pt.PivotFields(sField).Orientation = xlColumnField

End Sub
```

Pivot Fields
[image]

Comment: The code above is working without problems! Check the content of your variable `sField`.

Comment: From what I can tell, its returning the correct sField text from my button and the button matches the column name. I'm going crazy here.

Comment: Have you checked `sField` for additional spaces? Don't compare visually but in the code or in the immediate window (CTRL G).

Comment: Create the code you need with the macro generator by deleting and adding the pivot field and compare the above code with the generated code.